# How to register a macro programmatically?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, batch, macros, visual-basic

I have like 700 machines in which I need to deploy a new macro we have created. Is there any way to do this via cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, save the macro on your hnormal.dot, you can copy this file to all the machines.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-the-normal-template-normal-dot-HP001121028.aspx